# Make a json data on PHP from the name of local folders, and the data inside of text files

Tags: php, json, local

I would like to output the jason data which looks like a picture below on PHP. `folder` is the name of the folder, and `title` is located at the firstline of `info.txt`. There are three lines in each `info.txt`, and those lines are separated just by making new lines (not commas). folder `books`, and my `php` file is located under the same folder. How can I write a PHP code? Thanks.
MY PHP code is here;

```
function books(){

    $array = [];
    $story = glob("books/" . "*");

    foreach($story as $each){
        $title = file($each ."/info/txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $output = array (
            "title" => $title[0],
            "folder" => $each, #i would like to put the name of the folder here
            );
        array_push($array,$review);
    }
    print(json_encode($array));
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `How can I write a PHP code?` Open editor and write code.

Comment: Oh I totally fogot to put my code here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop over all folders you can use this:

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
```

Use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the `info.txt` files.

```
$books = array();
foreach($dirs as $dir){
   $books[$dir] = file($dir)[0];
}
```

Build your JSON as an associative array and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Save the JSON file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).